# Desperate need of help - Face ID stopped working on blockchain wallet app and I don't remember password

Tags: blockchain.info, wallet-recovery

First of all, apologies if this is the wrong forum for this.  I've contacted blockchain support and twice all I have gotten was a standard form response that says they cannot reset passwords, which is clearly not what I am asking.  I use the Blockchain wallet app on iphone X (Version 12.0.1).  I have been logged into the app since I downloaded it and set it to log in with FaceID which it has done every time I have used it.  A few days ago, I attempted to login as usual and came to find that when i open the app it says "Password Required".  "You have logged out or there was an error decrypting your wallet file.  Enter your password below to login."

The problem that I am facing is that I do not remember my password, nor do I have my 12 or 24 word seed.  To make matters worse, I do not even have my wallet identifier written down.  There was no email account associated with the account either.  So am I completely screwed?  I ideally need to find a way to get the FaceID to work again while still remembering the account.  Is there a way for me to obtain the wallet identifier from the app?  What should I do and what should I not do to make things worse?  If I guess various passwords that it could be, would it lock me out after a certain number of guesses?  Lastly, do you have any idea what would cause this to have happened in the first place?  Thanks in advance for any help you may be able to offer me.

Answer (score 3):

Most of the issues you're encountering are limited to the proprietary processes used by the blockchain app you are using, and only their support will be able to navigate you through them. Concepts such as face ID, wallet ID, etc. are not standardized by the bitcoin implementations, and vary from provider to provider.

If you're lucky, when Face ID is disabled, whatever scheme they used to decrypt the wallet via Face ID is not deleted, and may be recoverable with someone from the company helping you. However, a well designed wallet would likely remove any secret used to grant access via secondary authentication such as Face ID if the authentication's validity was in question, and fallback to a password based decryption instead.

From a general bitcoin perspective, without the backup seed words, you essentially have no bitcoin, unless you are able to get someone who knows the app's processes to help you recover any information that may remain. Even after that, it is highly likely that the information is encrypted in a manner which prevents anyone from accessing it without the password.

Answer (score 0):

> **I do not remember my password, nor do I have my 12 or 24 word seed ... I do not even have my wallet identifier written down.**

https://www.blockchain.com/learning-portal/security says

> In the event that you lose your Wallet ID (or worse your password), your Backup Phrase is the only way you’ll be able to regain access to your funds. Reminder: we’re a non-custodial wallet which means we can’t reset your password.

---

> **What should I do**

1. Use IOS facilities to backup all the data associated with your wallet on your iPhone. Blockchain support should be able to help with this.
2. If you have a life-changing amount of Bitcoin in that wallet, you may want to lock your Phone somewhere safe (e.g. bank safety deposit box, fireproof safe in your basement etc)  until you remember your password. Having your phone stolen or dropped into a river or some other mishap would complicate recovery (how did you not ever think about this?). Buy another phone to use in the meantime. You might need to periodically charge the old phone and plan for battery replacement (not a supported feature AFAIK but probably doable in extremis)
3. Ask Blockchain support if anything bad happens if you enter wrong passwords too many times?
4. Expect that unless you remember your password, your Bitcoin are forever lost to the world (20%-30% of all Bitcoin ever mined are said to be lost from this sort of situation)
5. Next time you download a wallet and put money into it, practise recovering access on a separate computer. Think about how your heirs can get access to your wallet contents if your plane crashes or the proverbial bus hits you.